# Как зафиксировать колонку в таблице с помощью bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Есть две колонки, левую колонку не получается зафиксировать, прошу помощи,, вот код, я оставил коммент где много текста картинок будет и который должен прикручивать, а левый должен зафиксироваться

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Панель управления</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fontawesome.css' %}">
    <style>
    #navigator {
      background: #ccc;
      height: 100vh:
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="navigator">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="logo d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <h3 class="text-white pt-2">BrosBurger</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id='close-btn'><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></div>
                </div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <ul class="list-menu pt-3">
                        <li class=""><a
                                class="text-white {% if request.path == '/admin/' %}btn btn-info btn-block{% else %}btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block{% endif %}"
                                href="{% url 'dashboard' %}"><i class="fa fa-hotel"></i> Главная</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a
                                class="text-white {% if request.path == '/admin/current_orders/' %}btn btn-info btn-block{% else %}btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block{% endif %}"
                                href="{% url 'current_orders' %}"><i class="fa fa-pizza-slice"></i> Текущие заказы</a>
                        </li>
                        <hr class="hr bg-secondary">
                        <li class=""><a
                                class="text-white {% if request.path == '/admin/category_products/' %}btn btn-info btn-block{% else %}btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block{% endif %}"
                                href="{% url 'category_products' %}"><i class="fab fa-buffer"></i> Категории и Продукты</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class=""><a
                                class="text-white {% if request.path == '/admin/stock/' %}btn btn-info btn-block{% else %}btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block{% endif %}"
                                href="{% url 'stock' %}"><i class="fas fa-boxes"></i> Склад</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a
                                class="text-white {% if request.path == '/a1dmin/' %}btn btn-info btn-block{% else %}btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block{% endif %}"
                                href=""><i class="fas fa-dolly-flatbed"></i> Инвентаризация</a></li>
                        <hr class="hr bg-secondary">
                        <li class=""><a
                                class="text-white {% if request.path == '/admin/history_sales/' %}btn btn-info btn-block{% else %}btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block{% endif %}"
                                href="{% url 'history_sales' %}"><i class="fas fa-funnel-dollar"></i> История продаж</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a
                                class="text-white {% if request.path == '/admin/history/' %}btn btn-info btn-block{% else %}btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block{% endif %}"
                                href="{% url 'history' %}"><i class="fas fa-history"></i> История операций</a></li>

                        <li class=""><a
                                class="text-white {% if request.path == '/admin/users/' %}btn btn-info btn-block{% else %}btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block{% endif %}"
                                href="{% url 'users' %}"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i> Пользователи</a></li>
                        <hr class="hr bg-secondary">
                        <li class=""><a class="text-white btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block"
                                        href="{% url 'logout' %}"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i> Выйти</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" id="main">
            <div class="menu-bar row shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
                <div class="menu-bar-list col-12 ">
                    <div id='nav-toggle'>
                        <i class="main-icon fa fa-bars pt-2 fa-lg"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row main-body">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- main section  -->
                    Здесь длинный контенет 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант добавить в стили:

```
#navigator > div{
    position: fixed;
    max-width: inherit;
    background: #ccc;
}
```